# How to find out Account usage by user > particular date and how much time he used particular query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to query from snow flake db as part of monitoring process, How much time a user using snowflakedb to execute his queries after particular date. The purpose of this is, to prevent users to running long queries.

Account usage history is some thing I wanted to know. I'm very new to snowflakedb.

Is there any way to query from the metadata ?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a parameter called STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS to control long running queries. Set to the amount of time, in seconds, after which a running SQL statement (query, DDL, DML, etc.) is canceled by the system. Can be set for Account » User » Session; can also be set for individual warehouses.  The default setting is 172800 (2 days).

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Query history view for this requirement](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html)

There are many columns in this view you can see and use appropriately as per your requirement.

Example Query :

```
SELECT query_id, 
       query_text, 
       query_type, 
       session_id, 
       user_name, 
       warehouse_name, 
       start_time, 
       end_time, 
       total_elapsed_time, 
       compilation_time, 
       execution_time 
FROM   snowflake.account_usage.query_history 
WHERE  user_name = 'anyusername' 
       AND Cast (start_time AS DATE) >= 'yourdate in yyyy-mm-dd format' 
       AND total_elapsed_time > 600000 -- around 10 minutes in milliseconds or you can specify any number here 
       AND warehouse_name = 'your datawarehouse name' 
ORDER  BY execution_time DESC;
```